# @Include (multiple) with differents values of same var name in LESS

Tags: variables, import, scope, include, less

I would use LESS to do something , but I do not know if it's possible

My problem is the following:(exemples are not my real code, so it's just a very simplified version of the mecanism)

I defined a generic definition to a file: **generic.less**

```
.button {
    .@{subclassname} {
       color:@color;
       &:hover { color:@colorhover; }
    }
}
```

And I'd have a lot of files that use this generic code.

Two examples files that will use this pieces of generic code : 
**variation1.less :**

```
@subclassname : variation1;
@color : red;
@colorhover : white;
@import (multiple) "generic";
```

**variation2.less :**

```
@subclassname : variation2;
@color : green;
@colorhover : blue;
@import (multiple) "generic";
```

**The global LESS file contains :**

```
@import "variation1";
@import "variation2";
```

**Result expected :**

```
.button {
    .variation1 {
       color:red;
       &:hover { color:white; }
    }
}
.button {
    .variation2 {
       color:green;
       &:hover { color:blue; }
    }
}
```

**Result obtained :**

```
.button {
    .variation2 {
       color:green;
       &:hover { color:blue; }
    }
}
.button {
    .variation2 {
       color:green;
       &:hover { color:blue; }
    }
}
```

Because @var is defined by the last value. 
What is the best solution to obtain the desired result ? ( I want to keep the same variables name . )

Thank you in advance

**Edit :** | **Solution Founded :**

**variation1.less :**

```
& { 
@subclassname : variation1; 
@color : red; 
@colorhover : white; 
@import (multiple) "generic"; 
}
```

**variation2.less :**

```
& { 
@subclassname : variation2; 
@color : green; 
@colorhover : blue; 
@import (multiple) "generic";
}
```

Comment: Really appreciate the way you have formulated your question.

Comment: As I understand you need to learn mixins and how use them for repeatable code. (It *is* possible to get what you want the way like above with a few additional tricks but it's really really wrong way).

Comment: Well, to not sound unreasonable, here's [the trick](https://github.com/less/less.js/issues/2442#issuecomment-73839112) I mentioned above but the whole thing (repeating the code by including the same file again and again with redefined variables) is a perfect anti-pattern.

Comment: I tried with mixins , but I have not found any method to keep the variable names when I set.

Comment: I found another solution. Because " @import ( scoped ) " is not specified in the formal documentation LESS . So I fear that " gulp " can not compile my files .
**variation1.less :**
    `& {
    @subclassname : variation1;
    @color : red;
    @colorhover : white;
    @import (multiple) "generic";
    }`

**variation2.less :**
    `& {
    @subclassname : variation2;
    @color : green;
    @colorhover : blue;
    @import (multiple) "generic";
    }`

thx @seven-phases-max :)

Comment: That "another solution" is what I linked to.

Comment: Yes , i want say "i used another solution". Thx a lot and sorry for my bad english :S